# How to use camera resource with FaceDetector in android?

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

I want to use `FaceDetector` in android.
 I tried `FaceDetector` with a bitmap image and its working fine.

(with the help of: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-face-detection-on-android--cms-25212)

Now, I want to detect face, when camera is on. The documentation writes:

> Alternatively, a detector may be used within a pipeline structure, in 
>   conjunction with sources (e.g., CameraSource) and processors (e.g.,
>   LargestFaceFocusingProcessor), enabling you to construct fairly
>   advanced detection pipelines with minimal coding. For example, the
>   code below creates and starts a pipeline that continuously receives
>   preview frames from a camera source for the front facing camera, runs
>   detection on the frames, manages tracking of the most prominent face,
>   and delivers continuous update notifications over time to a
>   developer-defined "FaceTracker" instance.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector

The code it provides:

```
detector.setProcessor(
   new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(
     detector,
     new FaceTracker()));

 CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
   .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
   .setRequestedPreviewSize(320, 240)
   .build()
   .start();
```

I want to implement this in my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
                .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
                .build();
        detector.setProcessor(
                new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(
                        detector,
                        new FaceTracker()));

        try {
            CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, detector)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(320, 240)
                    .build()
                    .start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class FaceTracker extends Tracker
    {
        public void onDone ()
        {

        }


    }

}
```

but, unable to move forward. Can you please help me to code it further?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the face tracker sample code, which is similar.  It also handles getting camera permissions and activity pause/resume:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java

What problems are you encountering?

Note that the "prominentFaceOnly" option will only detect faces that appear relatively large in the camera preview (i.e., face is around 35% or more of the width of the preview image).